# upload succeeding but picture is not there

Tags: php

I have a php page that is supposed to store the uploaded image to my server. When I run this, I get the "Upload successful" message, but the picture has not been uploaded. 
What could it be?

update: can people please leave a comment as to why they down vote my question. I'm new here and I dont know why this question got down voted. thanks

```
<?

if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    if ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] > 0 )
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] . "<br />";
    else{
        // Add the original filename to target path.  
        $target_path = 'MemberPics\\user'.$userid.'.jpg' ; 
        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

        if(!$success) {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }else {
            echo "Upload successful, please go back to your home page";

        }       
    }
}   
 ?>
```

Comment: Possibly it is because your saving location is incorrect try this.
$target_path = 'MemberPics/user'.$userid.'.jpg' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you are running into is that you are saving the image in an incorrect location (An invalid one from the looks of your link syntax).

Either of these should work:

```
$target_path = 'MemberPics/user'.$userid.'.jpg' ;
```

or

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], "MemberPics/user" . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
```

Comment: That fixed the problem. But now I'm curious why "\\" didn't work. Acording to the php manual:"To specify a literal backslash, double it (\\\)."

Comment: Usually when navigating through your back-end file system, folders specify "folder/" possibly you may have mixed it up with "//" because I notice on websites when you try and use "\\" it changes them to "//". So maybe if you tried "//" instead it would work as well; I just use "/" because it's more standard practice.